# What is an alternative function for numpy.argwhere for numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I would like to locate the local maximum of a monochromatic image. 
The image is a numpy.ndarray, with dtype uint8.

The image has several points with the maxima value of 255. Therefore I intend to take the average of the positions to find the effective position of the maxima.

For a normal numpy.array, the following code would effectively return me the positions of the elements with have value equal to 255.

```
positions = numpy.unravel_index(image.argwhere(), image.shape)
```

Where image is the numpy.array object. However in my code, image is a numpy.ndarray object, leading me to receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'argwhere'
```

Is there an alternative function for 'argwhere' that works on numpy.ndarray ?

Comment: What exactly is `image`?  It isn't a `numpy` object.  In `numpy` `argwhere` is a function, not a method. image.argwhere()` only works if `image` is some derivative class that defines this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argwhere` is a function of the numpy library which should work like

```
np.argwhere(image)
```

Anyway, `np.array` is not a separate type, it is just another way to create a `np.ndarray`.
Try `type` on any numpy-array variable you like, it will always be a `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I made a careless mistake!